# Create a new <div> with .createElement()

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

Hi I'm new to Javascript, having problem creating and adding a new  to the **DOM**. *(I want to do this with native javascript not jquery)*.

When I click the **"Calculate"** button, I *very briefly* see the Text flash on the screen and then disappear. Nothing added to the DOM.

**Here is my JS script:**

```
function makeResponseBox() {
    document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function()
    {
        var responseBox = document.createElement("DIV"); //create <div>
        var para = document.createElement("P");//create <p>
        var text = document.createTextNode("Text");//
        para.appendChild(text);//append text to para
        var newDiv = responseBox.appendChild(para);// append <p> to <div> and assign to variable
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);//append as child to <body>
    }

}//close function (makeResponseBox)

window.onload=makeResponseBox;
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add Element to DOM</title>
    <script src="calculate.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="main">
<h1>Add Element to DOM</h1>


<form id ="form">

    <fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />


    </fieldset><!-- close fieldset -->

</form><!-- close form -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript is fine, but your `type="submit"` button causes the page to reload when clicked, so you don't see the change. If you change it to a `type="button"`, I think you'll see it working perfectly. (This is pretty common problem; I'll see if I can find an existing question with a good answer.)

Comment: thanks @apsillers that solved it straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the form is submitted so the page is reloaded

You need to add a parameter to your listener , say `function(e)` and call `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the listener.

example:

```
document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var responseBox = document.createElement("DIV"); //create <div>
    var para = document.createElement("P");//create <p>
    var text = document.createTextNode("Text");//
    para.appendChild(text);//append text to para
    var newDiv = responseBox.appendChild(para);// append <p> to <div> and assign to variable
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);//append as child to <body>
}
```

Or you could also change the type of your button to remove the submit function

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />
```

But then your `<form>` become useless and you could remove it

Comment: Thanks @Hacketo this works perfectly now. Changing the type to 'button' also works

Answer (score 1):

change your submit type to button which will avoid the reload

```
 <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />
```

and if you want to submit the form handle it from js